# How to get the response from qooxdoo qx.event.type.Rest?

Tags: qooxdoo

In the documentation at http://manual.qooxdoo.org/current/pages/communication/rest.html is stated that:

> Handlers receive a qx.event.type.Rest event that, among other
>   properties, includes the response.

But there is no response in qx.event.type.Rest - http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/apiviewer/#qx.event.type.Rest

How to get that response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the request object to access the response. The request object will return a qx.io.request.AbstractRequest [1] which will include some methods to query the response.

[1] http://demo.qooxdoo.org/devel/apiviewer/#qx.io.request.AbstractRequest